# iTunes batch check or uncheck "skip when shuffling" not working

Tags: itunes

iTunes 12.1.2.27

I think it used to work.  Batch select a bunch of songs -> Get Info -> Options -> Skip when shuffling.

If there are mixed values for "Skip when shuffling" in that batch, it used to  allow you to either uncheck all or check all.  It does nothing for me.

Comment: Confirmed - might be bug report time.

Comment: bug #20587068 submitted